# Java Program for Illustrating Subcritical Equilibrium

Tags: java, loops, iteration

I'm trying to write a program that will illustrate how neutron population converges to a subcritical equilibrium level. I've been working on this for the last couple of hours but haven't been able to come up with anything.

It essentially takes the following form:

x (Starting value) = 500

y (constant) = 100

z (constant) = 0.8

a = z * (x + y)

b = z * (a + y)

c = z * (b + y)

....

n = z * ((n-1) + y)

My initial plan of solving this was through using a lot of variables and printing each line as follows:

```
public class NeutronPopulation {

    public static void main (String [] args){

    double keff = 0.8;  
    int neutronPopulation = 500;
    int source = 100;

    double neutronPopulation1 = keff * (neutronPopulation + source);
    System.out.println("Generation 1: " + neutronPopulation1);

    double neutronPopulation2 = keff * (neutronPopulation1 + source);
    System.out.println("Generation 2: " + neutronPopulation2);

    double neutronPopulation3 = keff * (neutronPopulation2 + source);
    System.out.println("Generation 3: " + neutronPopulation3);

    double neutronPopulation4 = keff * (neutronPopulation3 + source);
    System.out.println("Generation 4: " + neutronPopulation4);

    double neutronPopulation5 = keff * (neutronPopulation4 + source);
    System.out.println("Generation 5: " + neutronPopulation5);

    double neutronPopulation6 = keff * (neutronPopulation5 + source);
    System.out.println("Generation 6: " + neutronPopulation6);
    }

    //This could go on until Generation 18 when the # of neutrons stabilizes around 400
}
```

The above strategy worked, but it seemed very cumbersome so I tried to iterate the process where the output from the first equation (neutronPopulation1) would be the input for the second equation. This is just the latest revision of my code but so far nothing has worked.

```
public class NeutronPopulation {

    public static void main (String [] args){

    double keff = 0.8;  
    int neutronPopulation = 500;
    int source = 100;

    while (neutronPopulation > 400){
        neutronPopulation = keff * (neutronPopulation + source);
        System.out.println(neutronPopulation);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and I've been searching for the last hour or two for a similar example to mimic but I'm not even sure what to search for. I looked at a solution using recursion and tried a few examples customized for the problem I'm solving but I couldn't get it to work. Any help or pointers will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: you are trying to print `x` but it's undeclared

Comment: My apologies, that was a "copy to SO" error. I edited my original post to reflect the current print statement.

Answer (score 2):

You initialize the `neutronPopulation` as `int`-> the results in the loop are converted to int. It was not the case previously as you used `double` variables.

```
double neutronPopulation = 500;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is partially using int and double in the same mathematical equation.
If you simply cast your equation to an int, you will multiply by zero because .8 as a double rounds to 0 as an int.

Once you change everything to a double, the formula never reaches 400.  I assume this is intentional.

You can change the level of accuracy by adding decimals at the end of the 400 in the while loop expression. For higher level of accuray, add more zeroes before the 1 in 400.000001. This will also increase the number of generations.

public class NeutronPopulation {

```
public static void main (String [] args){

double keff = 0.8;  
double neutronPopulation = 500;
double source = 100;
int generation = 1;
while (neutronPopulation > 400.00001){
        neutronPopulation = keff * (neutronPopulation + source);
        System.out.println("Generation: " + generation + ": " + neutronPopulation);
        generation++;
    }
}
```

}